# How should one treat important books of Judaism?

Tags: jewish-books, kedusha-holiness

I was considering buying a version of the Sefer Yetsirah, but wondering how I should treat it. It's not the Tanach, so I suppose it probably doesn't require being as careful. Even though my question is specifically about the Sefer Yetsirah, I would also like to learn how one should treat commentaries, editions of the Talmud, Zohar, Shulchan Aruch, even textbooks on Jewish history, etc.

Comment: http://www.torah.org/advanced/weekly-halacha/5762/bo.html#

Comment: HVL, thanks for your good question and welcome to the site; I hope you stick around and enjoy it. Please consider registering your username: this will afford you a better site experience.

Comment: HVL maybe you can clarify what ways of treating you are referring to because as it is now the answer is 'respectfully'.

Answer (score 1):

All Torah works are considered holy and must be treated with respect, regardless of the specific genre (halacha, Talmud, kabbalah, etc.), even if the name of God is not mentioned in them. (This is true even if they are not written in Hebrew.)

The only difference between Torah works is that Biblical books are should not be placed underneath non-Biblical works, and Chumashim should not be placed underneath any other books, including other Bilical books.

Comment: Unless you are a certain type of sephardi who says that since you use a siddur daily, they should be placed on top of chumashim.  Or you have reason to believe that the "Torah book" you have really isn't Torah at all but pure superstition or avodah zarah.

Comment: @avi With regards to your first point, I'm not aware of such a position.

Comment: @avi With regards to the second, there certainly are works that, despite their appearances, are not legitimately Torah works and do not need to be treated with respect. (For example, I happen to own a Hebrew edition of the Christian Bible, including a Hebrew translation of the New Testament. Even though the work includes the full text of Tanach, it has no actual kedusha whatsoever.) However, if we are talking about a sefer that is broadly recognized in the traditional Jewish community as a legitimate Torah work, then it would be deeply problematic to unilaterally decide that it "isn't Torah".

Comment: @LazerA are you allowed to own that?

Comment: I'm talking about Berg translations of Kabbalah.

Comment: @LazerA There's a tshuva from R' Moshe on that. There might actually be some kedusha there, and how you can treat it depends (if I remember correctly), on whether the Tanach is printed in its own separate section of the book, or whether there are Christian commentaries alongside it. I couldn't find it after a cursory internet search and I don't have the physical books with me. If anyone happens to know the source, please comment it in.

Comment: The rule about vertical placement is talking about real sefarim on klaf, not our bound books. It is largely irrelevant today.

Comment: Also, in theory a klaf of one sefer from torah must be on top of a klaf for one sefer of neviim or ketuvim. See [here](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=11&daf=27&format=pdf)

Comment: @DoubleAA The Kitzur Shulchan Aruch (28:4) applies it to modern books, and I am not aware of any authorities that disagree.

Comment: @HachamGabriel Good question. For various reasons, I don't believe it is a problem for me to own, but it isn't a simple matter.

Comment: @LazerA I'm confused. Would he hold the same thing if I printed all the words in the torah on separate sheets of paper and piled them in arbitrary order and stapled the corner? A bound book is basically the same thing. This is not what the gemara was talking about when it said 'sefer'. I agree we treat it with respect as it represents "Torah". But no special dinim.

Comment: @DoubleAA Interesting question (although chumashim always have a least a few entire verses on most pages). In any event, I'm not sure I agree with your reasoning that a bound book is the same same as random pages stapled together.

Comment: 1) Even with some complete psukim doesn't make it a sefer. 2) Each page in a book is connected to another arbitrary page somewhere down the line.

Comment: Also, you are still assuming that printing is as good as writing for purposes of kavod. Yet do you stand up when a chumash is moved?

Comment: The kitzur does not apply the ruling to modern books, it applies it to book written in the 1600s or earlier.  Please don't confuse that issue.

Comment: @DoubleAA Yes, an actual sefer Torah, i.e. handwritten on a parchment scroll, must be treated with even more respect. The Kitzur speaks about both and applies the laws regarding piling seforim to printed and bound books. avi The Kitzur was written in the mid-19th century and is definitely referring to printed and bound books like we have today (and which were already in widespread use in the 1800s!).

Comment: @LazerA I agree the kitzur is talking about bound books. I am strongly questioning his ruling, as have many other poskim (not that I am a posek) (technically i haven't seen it inside).

Answer (score -1):

Generally, how you treat a book is not based on its relative Kedusha level, but rather if Gd's name is in the book or not.

The relative Kadosh levels of books only really comes into affect when you are stacking books ontop of eachother, or placing them in a bookshelf. (See Shulhan ARuch Yoreh Deah 282:19  for more details)

But how you treat the book itself, depends entirely on if Gd's name is in the book, or if it's from tanach.

Comment: See Shulhan ARuch Yoreh Deah 282:19

Comment: I don't see anything there that contradicts what I wrote. They are two separate issues.

Comment: Just a supporting source perhaps.

Comment: Oh, I thought that was the reason for the -1 vote.